# After upgrade livereload missing on real device, cannot debug js remotely from real device

Tags: react-native

After updating react native from 0.26 to 0.29, live reload and hot code push items are missing in dev menu, so I have to manually reload the app every time. However, it's working in simulator. Have I messed up something while upgrading? I tried to update to 0.30, but didn't help.

Also, remote debugging from real device doesn't work, works only while running app in simulator. I get this error: 
**Runtime is not ready for debugging**, but I'm sure that packager server is running, it's not paused on breakpoint. Any ideas?

React version: 15.2.1
Watchman version: 4.5.0

Thanks :)

Comment: Strange issue. I'm running `0.29.2` and the live & hot menu items are present. If you haven't already I would delete the app, and reinstall from XCode. Also, delete the javascript cache `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Yes it is strange, I tried what you suggested but didn't help. I tried it also on new project inited using 'react-native init testProject', but there's the same issue. When I tried creating new project with react-native@0.27 using rninit, it works, I can debug and there is livereload and hotcode reload. Cannot it be something with jsCodeLocation in AppDelegate.m? In 0.27 you had to specify IP address, now documentation says you should just uncomment line with [jsbundle mainbundle], but I don't see any line commented out...

Comment: Maybe, but I'm also using the new `AppDelegate.m` setup, but it's configured for [react-native-navigator](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) so it's a little different. Maybe it's bug related to the device your using. I'm running on an iPad it that helps. If you don't get any answers here, maybe you could [file an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues)

Comment: I tried it both on iPhone 6 iOS 9.3.3 and iPad mini 2 iOS 9.3.2, same situation there. I thought I screwed up something device specific, but when I start new project RN@0.27, I have live reload and hot code push and debugging on both devices. Anyway, I'm gonna make an issue on github. Thanks for help.

Comment: Link to github issue? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Hmmmm, I just realized I'm using 0.30 and I've always been using it. So I think we did something else wrong.

The only thing I've done lately is import some libraries, then remove those imports.

I find it so strangely that half the buttons are missing, when the compilation still works and the app is rendered... also for me reloading simply doesn't work.

Comment: I tried checking out a previous commit that I know worked, and had hot reloading. Still doesn't. Like changing code in React-Native seems to have the possibility of corrupting things without ever being able to reverse the corruption.

Is there a way to maybe clean everything in react native?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out the needed configuration for make live reload work:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://192.168.0.200:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

*note also that without "?platform=ios&dev=true" Hot Reload didn't work for me ("Unbalanced calls start/end" errors).*

and in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:

```
host = @"http://192.168.0.200";
```

192.168.0.200 - address of your computer. Both computer and device have to be in the same network.
After that "Live Reload" item in "shake" dev menu appeared and also i started to see logs in server console:
 [image]

and also "gotta be on the same wifi network" as @jmancherje mentioned

Comment: I didn't even need to add the server. The extra params and bundle were enough to get my live reloading working again. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to set App Transport Security in info.plist to allow http calls: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html

Comment: I just started a brand new project and these two steps did not fix the errors for me. Remote debugging is throwing errors and hot reloading is not present in the dev menu

Comment: And for me, just changing to the correct computer IP did it (although obviously a later version now)...

Comment: omg...@jmancherje...i spent two hours trying to figure that out and didn't think of that!

Comment: Oh wow! @jmancherje I had this problem, and thanks to your comment I  just turned wifi back on on my phone and it's now working! Thanks!

Comment: Finally, I figure out what the answer means... That is the url passed to RCTBridge instance, like this: 

```instance = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"] moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];```

Find the similarly code and fix the url entry.

Comment: Any advice on how to do it on RN 0.44? The AppDelegate.m and RCTWebSocketExecutor.m files are different now.    RCTWebSocketExecutor.m is `NSString *host = [[_bridge bundleURL] host] ?: @"localhost";` and AppDelegate.m is `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

Comment: @ArvinFlores - I just made it work on 0.54 with an almost identical change to the original answer (I just changed "index.ios.bundle" to "index.bundle").  This is definitely working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your jsbundle is not loading with real device, you have to use this for your live build when you archive build and install it.

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

and use following line for installing from xcode

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

[image]