# How to enable Live Reload in iOS Device running React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, livereload

I'm trying to enable Live Reload mode, but there is no such item in Dev Menu:
[image: no item called 'Live Reload']

Comment: It's weird. What version of xcode and react-native your running?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676746/after-upgrade-livereload-missing-on-real-device-cannot-debug-js-remotely-from-r

Comment: react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.30.0 Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)  Watchman 4.6.0

Comment: Finally fixed that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676746/after-upgrade-livereload-missing-on-real-device-cannot-debug-js-remotely-from-r

Comment: Hey @protspace make it as actual answer if it works for you. it will help others.

Answer (score 26):

You have this problem is mainly because your device and your development machine is not in the same LAN. check if it is. Make sure your computer and your device connected in the save LAN, everything will be ok.

After all ur devices connected to the same LAN. And if u are using Xcode.

1. Close the React Native packager (or just close the terminal window)
2. Delete the app in your iOS device
3. Clean Xcode project.
4. Run command `npm start -- reset-cache`

Then everything will be OK.

Comment: This one got me. I had multiple WIFIs around and my iPhone and MBP were bouncing to different ones while working and I didn't even realize.

Comment: @dwilt sometimes just connect to the same LAN can not solve this problem. So i updated my answer.

Comment: just switching to the same Wi-Fi worked for me ......Thanks  @Bruce Lee

Answer (score 10):

You need to edit the source for `jsCodeLocation` from your AppDelegate.

The main problem that the

`jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

is looking for `localhost` by default, in simulator it will work as simulator and pc are on the same machine, but for device `localhost` will be different so to make it work, you need to change that line to

`jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.16:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true"];`

here `192.168.1.16` change it to your PC local IP address

Comment: Projects created with v0.49 or later should use `jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.16:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=true"];`, since [new projects have a single entry-point](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0).

Answer (score 4):

If u are using IOS Simulator, follow the menu `Hardware > Shake Gesture`, and click the `Enable Live Reload` option.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the simulator, make sure you sure you "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a local ethernet connection that was taking priority on en0, so I had to change the script at:

`node_modules/react-native/react-native-xcode.sh`

from

`IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)`

to

`IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en1)`

since my wifi was on that port.
Verify that with terminal: `networksetup -listallhardwareports`

---

All this I learned from the following blog post:

https://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/react-native-bundle-loading-failing-on-a-physical-device

Thanks Steve Trefethen!

---

I'm not sure what the permanent solution should be, but it seems the script should be checking for wifi only connections somehow.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running the app on your actual native device. Then shake the device and it will pop up the me menu.

Comment: as you can see above I made a screenshot of that menu and there is no such item in it @Shivam Sinha

Comment: That's not what the op is asking.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the question. He asks how to get a normal menu with Live reload.