# How to enable Live reloading in iOS device, react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using react native for the development..I am able to see the option live reload in simulator but it is missing in iOS device..Please find the screenshots for the same..I would appreciate any help on how to enable live reload on device

On Simulator

[image]

On Device

[image]

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772373/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-ios-device-running-react-native-app

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your device and your packager are not running on the same network. Make sure your device is connected to the same Wifi as your development machine.

Comment: Hey I am connected on same wifi :(