# Hot/Live reload on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to enable hot/live reload on iOS device but when I shake the device there is no any "reload" option. 
I am runnining

1. Mac Os X - El Capitan
2. Xcode - 7.3.1
3. React Native - 0.40

When I change localhost to my IP address insight AppDelegate.m as suggested here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676746/after-upgrade-livereload-missing-on-real-device-cannot-debug-js-remotely-from-r) there is a Hot Reload Button but there is an error (showed below, the red screenshot).

[image]

[image]

I added screenshots from AppDelegate.m and RCTWebSocketExecutor.m

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I type my ip address in the browser like so:
http://myIpAddress:8081 it shows:
React Native packager is running.

Comment: Can you post a print screen here?

Comment: What do you mean by `hot/live reload`?

Comment: What options appear on the dev menu?

Comment: Again updated. Hot reloading appeared when I changed the localhost to my ip address but I have the error above.

Comment: Do you use proxies?

Comment: No, I don't. In the office we have router. I go to Settings->Network (turn off the ethernet, so I have only the WiFi (my phone and the computer use the same network) and get the ip from there -> added one image more

Comment: Can you try deleting your application, clean the project and reinstall it again? If this won't help I would continue with updating Xcode.

Comment: Make sure the packager is running before you start. Since the packager is just a server compiling the bundle on every request you can just visit the url manually in the browser.

For my setup this is:

http://localhost:11801/index.ios.bundle

Try visiting the url manually. 

Is there a reason why you don't want to connect from localhost?

Comment: Nope, there is no reason. But when the url so to localhost I do not have "Enable Hot Reload" button so I cannot test live on a device. On the simulator everything is working fine.