# How to connect device to development server on React Native 0.44?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, react-native

I've been at this for hours and cannot figure it out. I'm trying to connect my physical iPhone device to the dev server running on my laptop and cannot get it to connect. I keep receiving this error when I tap Debug JS Remotely after I shake my device to open up the Debug tools.

[image]

Additionally, the options Hot Reload and Live Reload do not show up in the Debug tools. I saw from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676746/after-upgrade-livereload-missing-on-real-device-cannot-debug-js-remotely-from-r) that the issue might be because I'm not specifying my computer's IP address in AppDelegate.m and RCTWebSocketExecutor.m, but the files are different from what the answer is suggesting and they now look like this.

AppDelegate.m

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

RCTWebSocketExecutor.m

```
NSInteger port = [[[_bridge bundleURL] port] integerValue] ?: 8081;
NSString *host = [[_bridge bundleURL] host] ?: @"localhost";
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%zd/debugger-proxy?role=client", host, port];
_url = [RCTConvert NSURL:URLString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The firewall on MacOS was blocking incoming connections for the node process running on my machine. To disable the firewall:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Security & Privacy -> Firewall
3. Click Firewall Options
4. Find the node option and change it from Block Incoming Connections to Allow Incoming Connections

Answer (score -1):

As a complete wild guess, you could try putting `host` in your Info.plist file and setting it to your dev machines IP.

Comment: No luck with that.