# React Native Debug Error on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-debugger

I have been developing React Native for a while and I keep updating myself with new release of the framework by creating other new project to test. Currently I face problem when I reload the application in Debug mode on my old version of React Native.

Every time I reload, It displays Cached Bundle on Chrome as below

[image]

On my device

> Runtime is not ready for debugging....

[image]

After going through googling, I follow these recommendation

- reset watcher, uninstall/reinstall watcher
- remove node_modules and reinstall it

But none of the solutions work.

*Notes

- react: v 15.4.2
- react-native: v0.42.3
- os: ios
- this error does not happen if I do not debug

Comment: You may follow the issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6682), which contains different `workarounds`, since it can be caused due to many reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Pritish. I found one comment helpful there. "Instead of http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui change it to http://127.0.0.1:8081/debugger-ui." I don't understand why localhost not working :(

Comment: Did the yarn run? Are you using the Wifi or cable to run the App on your cell phone?

Comment: @Reza : I am using Wifi. My computer and device are connected to the same network.

Comment: I still face the issue after changing url to "127.0.0.1:8081/debugger-ui" though I tried to clear application data and disable Network's cache. But running Chrome in **incognito** mode bring back the debugger. So this issue must be the cause of cache in Chrome.

Comment: I think it may help you, your jsbuldle is not loading https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765592/6949118

Answer (score 2):

After trying a lot of things, I just cleared browsing data(cookies and cache) of my google chrome and then started debugging and error is gone.